# Unknown host excpetion issue with proxy settings

Tags: java, network-programming

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class testprop {
    public static void main (String args[]) 
        throws IOException, URISyntaxException {


        // to check wether proxy working or not

        Properties p = System.getProperties();
        p.setProperty("proxySet", "true");
        p.put("https.proxyHost","proxy servername");
        p.put("https.proxyPort","80");
        System.setProperties(p);

        //if i uncomment the below line i am getting  Glib GIO error org.gnome.system.proxy is not installed
        //System.setProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies", "true");
        try {
            Proxy p1= (Proxy) ProxySelector.getDefault().select(new URI("http://google.com")).iterator().next();

            System.out.println("ProxyString"+p1.type());

            InetSocketAddress addr=(InetSocketAddress)p1.address();

            if(addr==null)
                System.out.println("no proxy");

            else{
                System.out.println("Proxy hostname" +addr.getHostName());
                System.out.println("Proxy port" +addr.getPort());

            }

            System.out.println("done");

        } catch (URISyntaxException uo){
            System.out.println("done3");
        }

        String str="google.com";

        try{
            InetAddress ip=InetAddress.getByName(str);
         System.out.println("the ip address of servicenow is"+ip);
        }catch (UnknownHostException ue){
            ue.printStackTrace();
         System.out.println("website not found");
        }    
    }
}
```

I am in an enterprise network,so to access internet I have to go through proxy.The above code is not setting the proxy for the next connection.Throwing an unknown host exception.
Is there any way I can achieve this?
Setting proxy so that external URL will be passed through proxy server.

Out put of the above code:

output:

```
ProxyStringDIRECT
no proxy
done
java.net.UnknownHostException: google.com: No address associated with hostnamewebsite not found
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:901)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1293)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1246)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1162)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1098)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:1048)
```

at testprop.main(testprop.java:49)

Comment: Please add the complete stacktrace.

Comment: Please add it to your question using the edit function. Not as a comment.

Comment: Is it possible, that you have no access to a dns server?

Comment: @jens chnaces are there.If you think that is the issue how can i resolve it?

Comment: Try to use the ip address of `www.google.de` and try if it works.

Comment: @jjens when i use ping command it is not working saying the same unknown host exception but with wget command it is fetching the google.com index html  successfully.

Comment: Have you tried to use the ip address instead of the server name?